# Softkeyboard overlapping by fragment after pip mode activeted first time

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-picture-in-picture

Maybe someone can help me with strange issue...
When I open chat screen and click on edittext I got resized screen (with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`) and keyboard.

[image]

But after I go to pip mode FIRST TIME and back it looks like this:

[image]

Very strange fact that if I going to pip mode one more time it will back to normal.
With tests I found that keyboard opened but overlapping by something, I made my DialogFragment not full screen and saw this:

[image]

This happens on samsung and xiaomi android 10 and 11 but on Pixel with android 13 not happens.
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on the keyboard screen adjustment, even if it still has the same issue check the comparability of the Keyboard which you're using.
getting Blank screen also caused by the Glitch and Bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't added below this code

```
<activity
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" ... >
...
</activity>
```

OR

```
add "adjustPan|adjustResize" or onCreateView of fragment add getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: yes, I tried to add stateVisible, don't have effect